# Solution to open/load multiple external link in react based web-app which is available as PWA in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I'm building **react** based **web-app** which is available as **PWA in iOS**. I have done so much R&D to solve my problem, but ended up with nothing. If anyone can help, it would be **appreciated**, let me explain the **problem in detail**:

In my web-app (PWA in iOS), there's a dashboard where list of **external links** are available, when you clicks on any link, it opens that link in in-app browser rather than a mobile's native browser. The **reason why I want this** is...

As I said there are list of applications, so, for example, let's say I'm clicking on **link-1**, the PWA opens the in-app browser, I'm login into that web-app, doing some work, then **coming back** to dashboard (PWA), and clicks on **another link-2**, it opens that web-link in in-app browser again, I'm login into that web-app, doing some work, then coming back to dashboard, now, when I'm clicking on **link-1 again**, it opens that in the in-app browser, and **I have to login again** go into the page I was on and do my work. This is little frustrating for user to having login again and again.

As I said these are external application, which means **I don't have control over it**, so **can't store the token** and pass it again when user clicks on the link.

I want somewhat like browser like experience where in, user does not lose his progress, even if he has opened multiple links from the dashboard, he can easily switch between the tabs.

The solution that I tried so far:

1. **Open directly PWA** of a link that I'm trying to open when click on link
   (the **iOS doesn't support** this yet)
2. Open the mobile's native browser
   (though **business doesn't want this**, as it's not good experience as user have to **switch between PWA and browser**, but still this is the **only solution** I can see)
   (I tried `window.open`, `_blank`, but no luck with that in iOS, though it **works well in Android**)
3. **Tried** many solutions like: `rel='external'`, `_blank` options, etc.
   (but no luck so far.)
4. Tried loading external link in iFrame
   (Due to security reason, it **refuses to load external link**)

I'm open for any solution that can fulfill my need. Even if you don't know the answer, please do like the question, I'd really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!
Looking forward hear everyone's thought on this.